# How do I fix ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME when trying to GET an ipfs url?

Tags: error, ipfs

For example, I want to render some NFTs that have urls like this:

`ipfs://QmZ5fD3UTRh8ALZCpMdypHkhMQSXyi4yyCz3Ea19kPmtXg/0.jpg`

but when I try to fetch this uri in my react app, I get this error:

`GET ipfs://QmZ5fD3UTRh8ALZCpMdypHkhMQSXyi4yyCz3Ea19kPmtXg/0.jpg net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all tools, browsers, etc. support fetching IPFS content.

In general, there are a couple of options for you to load IPFS content:

### 1. Use a browser that supports IPFS links

- [Brave](https://brave.com/brave-integrates-ipfs/) browser started supporting IPFS in version 1.19
- [Opera](https://blogs.opera.com/tips-and-tricks/2021/02/opera-crypto-files-for-keeps-ipfs-unstoppable-domains/) launched IPFS support in Feb 2021

By installing one of these browsers, typing your IPFS uri into the search bar should load the resource.

### 2. Use a public IPFS gateway

- `https://ipfs.io/{your IPFS hash}`
- `https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/{your IPFS hash}`
- you can find a full list of public IPFS gateways here: https://ipfs.github.io/public-gateway-checker/

Public gateways route your IPFS request through an HTTP server. So doing something like
`https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/bafybeie7tfuh4fkcp27xfrpftly732kjrr6ioj7ypa45ilv7lhpsadykh4/0.jpg` would show your image.

---

In your case, since you are programmatically fetching content, you can parse the hash and append a public gateway url prefix to fetch the images.